# How do I mock a module/class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have ModuleA containing ClassA which refers to and depends on ClassB in ModuleB.

Eg. my CLassA code has

```
var foo:ModuleB.ClassB;
```

Now I want to reuse ModuleA in another app, but I do NOT want to use ModuleB. I thought I could simply create a copy of moduleb.ts called moduleb-mock.ts, comment out all of the method bodies and be good to go. The problem is that the TS Compiler is objecting to a Duplicate identifier at `export class ClassB`.

Is there a simple way to ask tsc to forgive me just this once? I realise that the proper answer is to refactor, but my new app is only a temporary thing which I will soon throw away.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that the TS Compiler is objecting to a Duplicate identifier at export class ClassB

That would *only* happen if

- you have both mock and non mock classes in the *same* file. (assuming you are using external modules)

  OR
- You have both mock and non mock classes in the same *internal module*.

PS: for internal vs. external modules : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: they are in different files. I should add I'm compiling using the palantir eclipse plug-ini to do my compilation which has compile-all-files=true PS. I'm a huge fan of your videos, keep em coming.